# Ursina parent windows

Tags: window, parent, ursina

Is there a way in the ursina game engine, to parent two separate windows together, with one always being in front of the other. Like if you were to load up the first window then the second where it will stay in front of it, but also be like together so if you switch tabs or click away, both windows will act as one.